# Pyodbc - Insert query Truncated

Tags: python, sql, insert, pyodbc, truncate

I am new to python, trying to run a piece of code, where i am dynamically assigning columns and its values to an insert query, it can be a query with 4 columns and 4 values inserted or 2 columns with 2 values

```
INSERT INTO dbo.MYDB ('COL1','COL2','COL3') VALUES ('A','B','C')
```

my problem is small queries run fine, but bigger queries are truncated

this is a good one which ran

```
INSERT INTO dbo.CUST (CUSTNAME,AGE,CITY) VALUES (?,?,?)
```

and this is the one which got truncated and hence failed (notice 3rd column truncated *QUAN...*)

```
INSERT INTO dbo.FACT (CUSTNAME,PRODUCTNAME,QUAN... VALUES (?,?,?,?)
```

I am storing this query in a variable (named *query*) and passing it to be executed like below

```
cursor.executemany(query, (values))
```

when i hover over this variable '*query*', it says its type as - **(variable) query: Any**

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve]. Specifically, show the code that displays the truncated INSERT statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is obviously `df.to_sql()`

Here's one example:

`DataFrame.to_sql(self, name, con, schema=None, if_exists='fail', index=True, index_label=None, chunksize=None, dtype=None, method=None)`

See the link before for more details.

https://www.w3resource.com/pandas/dataframe/dataframe-to_sql.php

If it doesn't work for you on the first try, keep at it. This is an amazing function, and it will do exactly what you want. Also, see the link below.

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/merging.html